# Aliases for celery tasks

Tags: python, celery

I am switching task naming scheme. There are parts of the code which still use old names, and some which use new names. So, my question is: what is the proper way of aliasing Celery tasks?

```
@task
def new_task_name():
    pass

old_task_name = new_task_name  # doesn't work
app.tasks['old_task_name'] = new_task_name  # still doesn't work
```

I get error similar to this:

```
Received unregistered task of type 'app.tasks.old_task_name'
```

**UPDATE:**

My current solution is forwarding tasks. But I still hope there's a cleaner approach:

```
@task
def old_task_name():
    new_task_name.delay()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.task(name='this-is-the-name')
def new_task_name():
    pass
```

Comment: will this make my task accessible on both names? (as I need alias) or just 'this-is-the-name'?

Comment: It's just the name, cannot define alias

Comment: doesn't fit then, sorry :-/

Answer (score 0):

This question is ancient but a more direct way to do this is:

```
@task(name='old-name')
def old_task_name(*args, **kwargs):
    return new_task_name(*args, **kwargs)
```

Celery tasks can still be called as normal methods too.